# Easiest way to call a Windows macro from Autohotkey (or VB)?

Tags: windows, vbscript, macros, autohotkey

I have the following Macro I want to call from within an AutoHotkey script in order to set certain dates in my MonthCal object to be bold.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774722(VS.85).aspx

How would I go about that?

Note that it's possible the easiest way to do it is to write a simple VB script which uses the macro and call that. But I am entirely clueless about VB scripts. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following script [on the AutoHotkey forums](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic14695.html) via their great [IRC channel](http://mibbit.com/?server=irc.freenode.net&channel=%23ahk) (thanks _rhys and Titan)

```
monthNb := 3   ; How many months are displayed. Can be fetched with MCM_GETMONTHRANGE
MCM_FIRST := 0x1000
MCM_SETDAYSTATE := MCM_FIRST + 8

; MCS_DAYSTATE = 1
Gui, Add, MonthCal, +0x1 vMyCalendar
Gui, Add, Button, gBoldify w100, B
Gui Show

Gui +LastFound
guiID := WinExist()
ControlGet mcID, Hwnd, , SysMonthCal321, ahk_id %guiID%

Gosub SetDayState
Return

Boldify:
VarSetCapacity(daysBuffer, 4 * monthNb, 0)
if bOdd
{
   days = 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31
}
else
{
   days = 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
}
bOdd := not bOdd
addr := &daysBuffer + 4
Loop Parse, days, `,
{
   o1 := (A_LoopField - 1) / 8
   o2 := Mod(A_LoopField - 1, 8)
   val := *(addr + o1) | (1 << o2)
   DllCall("RtlFillMemory", "UInt", addr + o1, "UInt", 1, "UChar", val)
}
Gosub SetDayState
Return

SetDayState:
   SendMessage MCM_SETDAYSTATE, monthNb, &daysBuffer, , ahk_id %mcID%
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```